# Run PowerShell script from Pycharm IDE (Mac OS)

Tags: python, powershell

So I want to run a PS script that I have in my Python code, I just found this article: https://data-geek.medium.com/running-powershell-script-with-python-53a908da7d34

Since I'm using MacOS, it I changed it:

```
import subprocess, sys

p = subprocess.Popen(["powershell.app",
              "/Users/myuser/Downloads/powershellscript.ps"],
              stdout=sys.stdout)
p.communicate()
```

I've got an error, I guess the problem is with powershell.app .

How can I execute this PS script from my Python code?

Answer (score 0):

instead of using "powershell.app" you want to use "pwsh". This is the command the starts up powershell

Comment: Maybe you can provide some information or links how `pwsh` works?

Comment: pwsh is the default command when running powershell from the terminal. Like when you type python3 in the terminal it starts python, if you type pwsh it starts a powershell session. So this command would be p = subprocess.Popen(["pwsh",
              "/Users/myuser/Downloads/powershellscript.ps"],
              stdout=sys.stdout)